# How I can get fileid from google drive Response?

Tags: javascript, php, response, google-drive-api

I want get file id from Response when upload file to google drive finished.
how to save id in var?(php or javascript)

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code that you are using to upload the file, then we can show you exactly how to parse the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JQuery, you can do this:

```
var id = $.parseJSON(response).id
```

in the handler for an Ajax-related call like `$.ajax`, `$.get`, etc.